# How to account for outliers in a histogram? - R/Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, histogram, outliers

I am wondering if there is a way to account for **outlier** in a **histogram** plot. I want to plot the **frequencies** of a random variable, which is very small and distributed around zero. However, in most of the cases I am considering I also have an outlier that complicates things. Is there a way to adjust the scale of the x axis in **R/Matlab** so that I can capture the distribution of the random variable I am considering and also show the outlier? Because normal ways to obtain the plot result in such a scale that all values are considered to be zero, and I want to show how they are distributed around zero. So ideally I would like to have the scales around zero accounting for very small numbers and than after a gap (which does not necessarily have to be proportional to the actual distance from zero) a bin to indicate the value of the outlier. And I do not want to remove the outlier from the sample.

Is such a thing possible in R/Matlab? Any other suggestions would be welcome.

Edit: The problem is not in identifying the outliers and using a different color for them. The problem is in adjusting the scales on the x-axis so I can observe the distribution of the variable as well as have the outlier included in the plot.

Comment: An alternative to using histogram bins also for outliers: you could indicate outliers by plotting each as a separate marker in the figure. This might work if there are not too many of the outliers.

Comment: @SamDickson The problem described in the question you referred me to is different than mine. Solution by Ander Biguri is what I have been looking for. I only need to slightly modify it as described in my other comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next code will do the job, but you need to change the Xticklabels of the axes in order to make them show the real value of the outliers.

```
A=rand(1000,1)*0.1;
A(1:10)=10;


% modify the data for plotting pourposes. Get the outliers closer
expected_maximum_value=1; % You can compute this useg 3*sigma maybe?
distance_to_outliers=0.5;
outlier_mean=mean(A(A>expected_maximum_value));
A(A>expected_maximum_value)=A(A>expected_maximum_value)-outlier_mean+distance_to_outliers;

% plot
h=histogram(A,'BinWidth',0.01)

%% trick the X axis
ax=gca;
ax.XTickLabel{end-1}=[ax.XTickLabel{end-1} '//'];
ax.XTickLabel{end}=['//' num2str(outlier_mean)];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! After some trial and error I have managed to implement your solution and it works almost perfectly. I have one more question. The numbers on my scale are very small with the x10-4 at the end of the plot. When I am applying your trick and substituting the labels somehow I lose this x10-4. Do you know how to implement your solution without losing it? Once again many thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Masher my first suggestion would be to reduce the value of `distance_to_outliers` to 3*sigma (assuming gaussian data) or to `2*expected_maximum_value`. Else you need to get to do harder tricks with the ticks.